# Generate Pipe Delimited .txt file from oracle database

Tags: shell-script, shell, pipe

I need help generating pipe delimited .txt file from oracle query. Select * from user

Comment: This question doesn't have enough information yet.  Can you clarify what you mean and/or give additional info?

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Preferences > Database > General Export parameter
Set Custom Export Delimiter to '|'

Run your query and, right-clicking anywhere in the data grid, select "Export Data - CSV"

I found this answer [On the Oracle Community site](https://community.oracle.com/thread/655917?start=0&tstart=0).